# UIview animation like Mac OS kernel panic

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview

When Mac kernel panic, there's animation, it's not like slide animation exactly, how to implement this animation in iPhone, is there a exist API to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API for that but it is fairly simple animation:
Simply create a `UIView` and animate its `frame`, changing from 0 height to full height:

```
   // Create your view
   UIView *kPview = [[UIView alloc] init];
   // Add it to your view
   [self.view addSubView:kPview]
   // Set its frame
   kPview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,0);

   //Set the animation
   [UIView animateWithDuration:5 
                 animations:^{
                     kPview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     //add a UILabel with the warning.
                 }];
```